# Select content without explicit data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have video table with columns (username, userId, ...) and a users table with columns (username, userId, explicitContent, ...).

explicitContent column have value 1 for adult content and 0 for general content.

I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM video 
   RIGHT JOIN users ON users.explicitContent = 0 
WHERE hashtags LIKE 'cats' 
ORDER BY created DESC
```

How to select videos with explcitContent = 0 ?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the problem ? Are you getting no rows ?

Comment: To which table does the column `hashtags` belong? There is also no join between video and users. You are missing a join condition as well.

Comment: I have duplicate columns and working only phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join on the `userid` field.  An outer join is not necessary:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM video v inner join
     users u
     ON v.userid = u.userid and
        u.explicitContent = 0 
WHERE hashtags LIKE 'cats' 
ORDER BY created DESC
```

Comment: Thanks man, worked. Your answer is much better because select only video columns.

Answer (score 0):

Join is used to connect tables togther using the primary key of users, and a foreign key of video. However, you need to add the condition `sers.explicitContent = 0` after the `where`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM video 
   INNER JOIN users ON users.userid = video.userid
WHERE hashtags LIKE 'cats'  AND
users.explicitContent = 0 
ORDER BY created DESC
```